# How to bulk borrow and download borrowable-only books programmatically from the Internet Archive?

Tags: api, web, download-manager, scraping, shell-scripting

How to bulk **borrow** and download those borrowable-only books programmatically from the internet archive?

And how can this be done?

Is there an archive.org API for borrowing books?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Internet [Archive](https://archive.org/) has an API details are [here](https://archive.org/services/docs/api/index.html).

There is a [command line tool](https://archive.org/services/docs/api/internetarchive/cli.html) and a [Python library](https://github.com/jjjake/internetarchive). You will however be limited to only borrowing a total of 10 books at any time, for 14 days, and may have to join a queue for a specific title.